# How to call ExpandedProductResultParser in Android Zxing

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, product, zxing

I have a Barcode scanner application which is built upon the great Zxing library. I wanted to know if I can make use of getLotNumber method by calling ExpandedProductResultParser etc in android activity. If yes, How?

"Getting Camera error in Zxing Barcode Application"
- this is the application i have built on based Zxing.

Now I want to extract Lot Number from the BarCode. What I have tried is this in onActivityResult() :

```
 String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            //String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_FORMATS");  

               Bundle bar=intent.getExtras();  

                System.out.println("Bundleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :::::::::::" + bar );  

                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");  
                System.out.println("Formaattttttttttttttt " + format);  





                Result result=new Result(contents, null, null, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128);  

                ResultParser.parseResult(result);  


            //ExpandedProductResultParser
```

Here, how can i pass actual format that is captured from barcode in Result()?
Also how can i make use of ExpandedProductResultParser.parse()
 method to get lotNumber?

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Intents? Yes, just use the class on the `String` you get back to parse it. What's the issue?